# How to inform a UserControl that an event has occurred in another UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml, event-handling

I have a Window called `MainWindow` which contains 2 UserControls:

```
SearchBox
```

and

```
CustomerList
```

When someone types into SearchBox I want to change CustomerList accordingly.

**Question:** What is the best way for `CustomerList` to know that the `TextChanged` event has been executed in `SearchBox`?

Right now I have `SearchBox` defined as:

```
public class SearchSubmittedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Term { get; set; }

    public SearchSubmittedEventArgs(string term)
    {
        Term = term;
    }
}

public partial class SearchBox : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<SearchSubmittedEventArgs> SearchSubmitted;
    public SearchBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchSubmitted != null) SearchSubmitted.Invoke(this, new SearchSubmittedEventArgs(((TextBox)sender).Text));
    }
}
```

and `MainWindow` has the following XAML and EventHandler:

```
<UserControls:SearchBox SearchSubmitted="SearchSubmitted_Invoked" />

private void SearchSubmitted_Invoked(object sender, SearchSubmittedEventArgs e)
{
    // I know SearchBox has been typed into

    // but I don't know how best to inform CustomerList
}
```

Do I need to pass the event from `SearchSubmitted_Invoked` to `CustomerList`? Is there a way for me to pass it directly from `SearchBox` to `CustomerList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just subscribe to the event...Something along these lines:

```
 var search = new SearchBox();
 var cust = new CustomerList();
 search.SearchSubmitted += (s,e)=>{ cust.Update(e.Term); }
```

Hope it helps you find a way to move along...

Answer (score 0):

Are those controls near each other? Then it would maybe make sense to bake a new user control with them inside. That outer user control is the one that should do the event handling.